# How to add an existing compiler for c to CodeLite without the CodeLite crash

Tags: c, compiler-errors, codelite

When I click on Build settings and  try to add a existing compiler  I choose the path of cygwin64 and then the folder bin but when I clicked "Select Folder" and then set name to the compiler and click "OK" the codelite crashed and I have no idea why can someone help me please

I expect to add an existing compiler to the codelite but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

When you are using CodeLite on Windows, check the CodeLite version.

If it is version 17.0.0 then simply update to version 17.4.0 or higher (if available).

https://downloads.codelite.org/